# Как вызывать одно и тоже контекстное меню для каждого элемента с одинаковым типом?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я знаю как вызвать контекстное меню для отдельного элемента:

```
<Button Content="12345">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="cm">
                <MenuItem Header="File"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
                <MenuItem Header="SaveAs"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Recent Files">
                    <MenuItem Header="ReadMe.txt"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Schedule.xls"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Но что если я хочу задать одно контекстное сразу для всех кнопок?

Comment: [How do I use the DataType property on a WPF DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424584/312041)

Comment: [Data Templating Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)